# Absolute continuity on limit

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> In probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, we have random variable $X$ that maps $\Omega$ into $R$. Assume $\mathbb{E}{|X|}<\infty$ and let $A_n$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{F}$ satysfying $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)=0$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} X dP =0$.

I have proved it when we know $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$ exists:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} X dP = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} 1_{A_n}X dP $

Since  $|X 1_{A_n}| \leq |X|$ , we can use Dominated convergence theorem. Therefore,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} X dP = \int_{\Omega} \lim_{n \to \infty}  1_{A_n}X dP  = \int_{\Omega}   1_{ \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n}X dP  = \int_{\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n}   X dP $

Then, by absolute continuity, I have claimed that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)=0$ yields $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} X dP =0$.

But, how we can prove this when we don't know $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know that $\lim_n A_n$ exists, nor do we need it for the entire sequence. Suppose for contradiction that $\limsup_n \int_{A_n} X dP > \epsilon > 0$. Then after passing to a subsequence we may assume that $ \int_{A_n} X dP > \epsilon$ for all $n$. Since $P(A_n) \to 0$ by passing to a further subsequence we may assume $\sum_n P(A_n) < \infty$. By a Borel-Cantelli lemma we know that the probability that infinitely many $A_n$ occurs is zero, in other words $1_{A_n} \to 0$ a.s. Now we can apply dominated convergence to get $0<\epsilon<\lim_n \int_{A_n} X dP = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: @ I wrongly voted negatively and I cannot change my vote until you edit it. Can you make a small change and edit it so I can give a positive vote?

Comment: Edited so you can correct your vote, thank you.